# Create RazorPDF for a list of partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razorpdf

I want to make a report in pdf form in asp.net mvc application and at the moment i am showing result as partial views, i.e., my main page is Report and is calling like

```
public ActionResult Report(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Id =id;
   return View();
}
```

And inside Report.cshtml i am calling 5 partial views to render 5 different sections of report
like this

```
<div class="row">
@Html.Action("Report1", "Screening", new { Id = @ViewBag.Id })
</div>
<div class="row">
@Html.Action("Report2", "Screening", new { Id = @ViewBag.Id })
</div>
<div class="row">
@Html.Action("Report3", "Screening", new { Id = @ViewBag.Id })
 </div>
<div class="row">
@Html.Action("Report4", "Screening", new { Id = @ViewBag.Id })
</div>
```

Now i want to make Report as a pdf and is any way to call Partial view directly from RazorPDF view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
public ActionResult Report(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Id =id;
    var model=new YourViewModel()
    return new RazorPDF.PdfResult(model, "Report");
}
```

Comment: No This is not working. First problem Viebag.Id is null at view level , but i managed to make it with help of a  model with id property and use the id property to pass value to view. But when the page is loaded i am getting an alert "There was a error with processing a page " and when i open pdf its giving message "there was an error processing a page. There was a problem readng this document (109)" . Any help to solve it